# Le « précis » pour l'exposé ou le résumé est-il vieilli ou sorti d'usage ?

Tags: usage, évolution

Depuis quand l'emploi de [*précis*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9cis) pour l'« exposé précis et succinct, résumé d'un ensemble plus vaste » (TLFi) serait-il vieilli et est-ce vieilli ou complètement sorti d'usage ou autrement ; s'est-on déjà vu demander de donner un *précis de quelque chose*, le comprend-on ? Ce vieux *précis* ne désignait-il uniquement qu'un exposé à l'oral ? Autrement, peut-on dire qu'un ouvrage (comme le [*Précis de grammaire française*](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/qf/1995-n99-qf1229588/44218ac.pdf) de Grevisse) est aussi, plus précisément, un *précis* dans ce sens-là ; ou non ; pourquoi ?

Comment: On peut noter par curiosité qu'en langue anglaise on aurait encore ça au [dictionnaire](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/pr%C3%A9cis) mais on m'a dit sur [ELU](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57386543#57386543) que soit on ne l'avait jamais entendu, soit on le trouverait peut-être prétentieux plutôt que sophistiqué, peut-être a fortiori dans un contexte militaire (l'oeuvre de Tom Clancy). Ensuite le lien vers l'article discutant du Précis de Grevisse contient un passage qui pourrait choquer certains lecteurs.

Answer (score 4):

Précis en tant que substantif (TLFi **II C.**), d'un charme un peu désuet, se rencontre encore dans les titres de petits ouvrages destinés aux étudiants du supérieur mais a essentiellementt disparu du vocabulaire de l'enseignement du primaire ou du secondaire.

Je ne l'ai jamais entendu être utilisé absolument<sup>1</sup> et ne comprendrait pas immédiatement une phrase utilisant la définition **II B.** comme par exemple *Est-ce que tu as terminé ton précis ?*

<sup>1</sup>  <sup>[Absolument: III. A.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/absolument) : Employé sans l'expansion attendue, employé sans autre qualificatif.</sup>

Comment: Juste pour être certain, un truc comme _tu leur donneras un précis de l'information dont tu disposes_ reste un emploi absolu et ne changerait rien à ton propos ?

Comment: Oui, ça entre dans cette catégorie pour moi..